range $T_1=$ range $T_2$ implies the existence of invertible linear operator $S$ such that $T_1=T_2S$
I'm trying to prove the following statement (from Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler):

Suppose V is finite-dimensional and $T_1, T_2 \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$. Then range $T_1=$range $T_2$ implies that there exists an invertible $S\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T_1=T_2S$.

This is my attempt:
Since $V$ is finite dimensional, so is null $T_1$. Let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be the basis of null $T_1$. This is a linearly independent list in $V$, so it can be extended to a basis of $V$: $v_1,\dots,v_n, e_1, \dots, e_k$.
The basis of range $T_1$ (and range $T_2$) is therefore $T_1e_1, \dots T_1e_k$. Let $f_i$ be an element of $V$ such that $T_2f_i=T_1e_i$ ($i=1,\dots,k$). Notice that $f_1,\dots, f_k$ is linearly independent in $V$, so it can be extended to a basis of $V$: $f_1,\dots,f_k, u_1, \dots, u_n$.
Define $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ as follows: $Se_i=f_i$ ($i=1,\dots, k$), $Sv_i=u_i$ ($i=1,\dots,n$).
For any $v \in V$ we have that $v=\sum a_iv_i+\sum b_i e_i$ for some coefficients $a$ and $b$.
Thus (summation over $i$),
$$T_2(Sv)=T_2\left(\sum a_iSv_i+\sum b_i Se_i\right)=T_2\left(\sum a_iu_i+\sum b_if_i\right)=T_2\left(\sum a_iu_i\right)+\sum b_iT_2f_i.$$
The second term in the above is
$$\sum b_iT_2f_i=\sum b_iT_1e_i = T_1\left( \sum b_ie_i\right)=T_1\left(\sum b_ie_i + \sum a_iv_i\right) = T_1v.$$
This is where I got stuck. I don't know if $T_2\left( \sum a_i u_i\right)=0$. I tried to prove it but didn't get very far. I was also wondering if it's possible to choose the basis extension $u_1, \dots, u_n$ so that this is a basis for null $T_2$ to avoid this problem but I'm not sure of that either.

"I was also wondering if it's possible to choose the basis extension $u_1,\dots,u_n$
so that this is a basis for null $T_2$ to avoid this problem but I'm not sure of that either."
You are correct. Let $u_1,\dots,u_n$ be a basis of null $T_2$. The length is $n$ since $\text{dim null }T_1=\text{dim null }T_2$ and the list $f_1,\dots,f_k,u_1,\dots,u_n$ is linearly independent since if $\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_jf_j+\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_ju_j=0$, then applying $T_2$ to both sides you have $\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_jT_1e_j=0$. The list $T_1e_1,\dots,T_1e_k$ spans range $T_1$ and is of the right length hence it's a basis of range $T_1$ so it's also linearly independent, therefor all $a_j=0$ for $1\leq j \leq k$ which follows that all $b_j=0$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$. Thus $f_1,\dots,f_k,u_1,\dots,u_n$ is linearly independent and of the right length (dim $V$) and so is a basis of $V$.

I noticed that the list would be linearly independent but overlooked the fact that it had the right length and was therefore a basis! Many thanks
